# Get all system fonts electron js

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, fonts, electron

I am building a desktop application using Electron.
In my app I have a window that sets some user preferences such ass background color for my app.I want to be able to show a select box which will contain all system fonts.Is that possible?

## UPDATE

My app is going to be cross platform so I would like a cross platform solution if possible

Comment: I think you need to make setup with fonts with .EXE

Comment: Have you checked out [font-manager](https://github.com/devongovett/font-manager)?

Comment: what is this? @HuguesMoreau

Comment: @ManosKounelakis It's a package for Node.js that offers the functionality you requested. Electron uses Node.js, so you can use Node.js packages (using NPM).

Comment: @HuguesMoreau you can post it as an answer so I can accept it .It will also be more helpful for others

Comment: Sure, done. Maybe the question deserves a [node.js] tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[font-manager](https://github.com/devongovett/font-manager) is a "module for Node.js providing access to the system font catalog", which seems to fit the bill.

Supported platforms:

- Mac OS X 10.5 and later supported via CoreText
- Windows 7 and later
  supported via DirectWrite
- Linux supported via fontconfig

Comment: Above package was showing error when installing. found an alternative that worked for me. https://github.com/oldj/node-font-list